# Static member rx cannot be using on instance type UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

so i started learning about rxCocoa, and tried to implement it into a collectionview,
I see no problem with tableview and it supposed to do the same with collectionView
But somehow this error showed up.

So how exactly to use rx bind ? and why the error showed up

Thank you

my View Controller

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var presenter:HomePresenter?
    private lazy var collectionView:UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (view.bounds.width/2)-2, height: 370)
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        return collectionView
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

// THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR STARTS
        presenter?.getProductList().bind(to: collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: ProductCollectionViewCell.identifier, cellType: ProductCollectionViewCell.self){a,b,c in
            
        }).dispose(by:disposeBag)
     }

}
```

[image: The Error]

my presenter

```
    func getProductList() -> Observable<[ProductEntity]> {
        return self.interactor.getProductList()
    }
```

Comment: I dont see a `static`. Where is the line causing the error exactly?

Comment: at presenter?.getProductLine, inside the viewdidload

Comment: i didnt use any static type except for the cellidentifier, but it usually works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your parens in the wrong place...

```
presenter?
    .getProductList()
    .bind(to: collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: ProductCollectionViewCell.identifier, cellType: ProductCollectionViewCell.self)) { a, b, c in // two close parens here

    } // no close paren here
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```